# Google Sheets Conditional Formatting By Compare Two Columns From Different Worksheets

Tags: google-sheets, count, formatting, google-sheets-formula, conditional-formatting

I am having data in two different sheets i.e. Sheet1 Col A and Sheet2 ColA, I want to highlight value in Sheet1 if the count of that value in Sheet1 is less than the count in Sheet2. E.g. in Sheet1 the count of number 1 is 5 and in Sheet2 the count of number 1 is 7 thus 1 should be highlighted in Sheet1. For ease of reference am sharing the image as well as the link of the sheet with desired result.
[image]

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bFhqJ_RIzf9J5vLD3PxTxSkv0KtNp1-xW6IxD_I8b4k/edit#gid=143258355

Any help on above will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
=COUNTIF($A$2:$A,$A2)<COUNTIF(INDIRECT("Sheet2!A2:A"), $A2)
```

Comment: @ Player0 thanks for your super quick and excellent solution as usual...